# como decirle a firebase que si hay un string vacío no lo guarde

Tags: reactjs, firestore

estoy guardando datos en firebase y es prácticamente la primera vez que utilizo este servicio, tengo un formulario de 4 inputs, al menos el primero debe contener algo, quiero guardar estos datos en firebase pero me esta dando un error, lo que quiero hacer es guardar los datos pero si hay un campo vacío que no se guarde, me explico? estoy guardando los datos de esta forma

```
db.collection("promociones").add({
      label1: value.label1,
      label2: !!value.label.label2 && value.label.label2,
      label3: !!value.label.label3 && value.label.label3,
      label4: !!value.label.label4 && value.label.label4,
      image: urls
    })
```

esto se guarda, pero en la colleccion me muestran los campos con un string vacio y yo quisiera que si esta vacios directamente no se guarden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que haría sería filtrar todos los `labels` antes de guardarlos en Firebase.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let objLabels = {label1, image}

let arrayLabels = [label2, label3, label4]

arrayLabels.map(label => {

    if (label != '') {
    
       objLabels[label] = label
    
    }
})
```

Ahí guardaría los `labels` que no sé si van a tener valores o no en un Array, los recorro luego con un `.map` y guardo en el objeto `objLabels` solo los `labels` que no estén vacíos.

Por último, a Firebase guardo todo el objeto cuyas propiedades solo van a ser los `labels` que tengan valores dentro...

```js
db.collection("promociones").add({
    objLabels
})
```